# Auto login on tty1 only (No GUI)

Tags: linux, centos, raspberry-pi, autologin

I have a few data collection machines that have been running on old PCs using CentOS 6 for a number of years.  I'm trying to set them up on a Raspberry Pi running CentOS 7.

Tty1 is set to auto login the user and start the collection program.  Tty5 is my backdoor into the system if I have to make changes on the shop floor.

I've gotten everything to work correctly on 7 except the auto login.  It works but wants to login the user on all terminals.  I did get this to work on minibian but I'm much more comfortable with CentOS.

Does anyone know how to setup auto login for a single terminal on centos 7?

Thank You,

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED:

Here's a link to the directions: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

Once there search for "How do I set automatic login on a virtual console terminal"

I wanted the user to be logged in on tty1 so I just substituted tty1 for tty8.  I did have to do some jockeying with the number as not to overwrite the default.

I ended up with the user autologging in to tty1 and the back door being tty5.

Comment: The link does not provide an answer anymore.

Comment: Please show us the relevant override.conf files in your /etc/systemd/system directory.
Thanks.